# Unstuck non-upgraded Parachain

Tags: parachain, rococo, runtime-upgrade

A parachain had an upgrade schedule on a relay chain, but the upgrade did not go through, forcing the parachain to stop `producing blocks`. I tried forcing a new `validationCode` using SUDO, but that did not work either, and the parachain is still waiting to upgrade.

[image]

What's the best solution to unbrick the chain? I don't need to recover any of it's state and ideally I want to remove it. For reference this is the current (March 23 2022) status of [paraID 2000 on Rococo](https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Frococo-rpc.polkadot.io#/parachains).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue appears to be that you have put your chain into an expected state, which it cannot resolve.

When calling `schedule_para_cleanup` we check:

```rust
// Disallow offboarding in case there is an upcoming upgrade.
//
// This is not a fundamential limitation but rather simplification: it allows us to get
// away without introducing additional logic for pruning and, more importantly, enacting
// ongoing PVF pre-checking votes. It also removes some nasty edge cases.
//
// This implicitly assumes that the given para exists, i.e. it's lifecycle != None.
if FutureCodeHash::<T>::contains_key(&id) {
    return Err(Error::<T>::CannotOffboard.into())
}
```

I am seeing that Para 2000 on Rococo does have a `FutureCodeHash`:

[image]

So the chain cannot be cleaned up until this is removed.

I am not sure how you got in this state, and it would be good for you to share that so that we may potentially handle these state transitions in the runtime better, but for now, probably you need to use Sudo to remove this storage item  manually, and then you can offboard your chain.

Comment: Thanks! This was actually an external team testing runtime upgrades, and I actually need this paraID to onboard another team to the network. Not sure how it got to this point, but I'll try and remove the storage item manually.

Comment: Would still be good if we can do a basic check on how this happened, since we would never want this state to be reached on Polkadot or Kusama.

Comment: The discussion tho that case was on this post: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/859/my-parachain-has-not-been-able-to-issue-a-block-after-submitting-the-upgrade-tra/